# remove item at a specific position in localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Hi i want to remove from the localStorage a specific item at a specific position.
If i have this JSON:

```
key: user_login
0: {
password: "aaaa", 
indirizzo: "via dei mille"
}

1: {
password: "kkkk",
indirizzo: "via garibaldi 6"}
```

Now i want delete JSON at position 0(password: "aaaa", indirizzo: "via dei mille").
I try:

```
var storedNames = localStorage.getItem("user_login_users");
arr1.slice(0,1);
```

But localStrorage don't remove nothing. With localstorage.removeitem(key) i can't remove all item at position 0. How can i do?

Comment: You said it yourself: it's JSON. And all JSON is is a String. To be able to manipulate the Object it represents, you need to first `JSON.parse()` it. Once you're done, you `JSON.stringify()` it and save it back with `localStorage.setItem()` (localStorage can only store Strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've retrieved the values from storage, you've then edit that value in-memory.
You'll then have to persist these changes, by writing them to the storage.

```
var storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user_login_users"));
// remove an entry
var newStoredNames = storedNames.slice(0,1);
// or change an existing one.
newStoredNames[0].password="my_new_value";
// persist the changes:
localStorage.setItem("user_login_users", JSON.stringify(newStoredNames));
```

Comment: thank you. And if i want to set a specific value in the user_login_users localStorage? For example storedNames[0].password="abcdef"? i try to write this code but the code don't work. If i use localStorage.setItem make a new localStorage and i want to write in the  user_login_users localStorage at the specific position.

Comment: You retrieve the latest value from local storage, make changes to the retrieved object, and use `setItem` to save the changes.